# Is it possible to use Android TV as the second monitor?

Tags: android

I have a modern Philips TV with Android (it's connected to my local network). I can simply cast the screen of my Android phone but Is it possible to use TV as the second monitor for my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 via wi-fi?

Comment: Please add more info about the TV (which model?). Do you mean through local network? If it has HDMI input is trivial.

Comment: Might be able if using Chrome browser(seems like best working).  Know with chromecast other browsers/apps do not work as well.  Will probably need android phone to setup if android TV works the same.  Google seems to only allow android stuff for setup(for chromecast)

Answer (score 3):

Your TV must have an HDMI port. You can certainly connect your laptop to the TV with a HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, with the proper Gnome Shell extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1544/cast-to-tv/

> Cast files to Chromecast, web browser or media player app over local network.
>
> Requires: npm nodejs ffmpeg